# Assigning dictionaries to list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Being new to Python, I am studying the following codes:

```
a_0 = {"what": "b"}
a_1 = {"what": "c"}
a_2 = {"what": "d"}

items = [] # empty list

for i_no in range(10): # fill the list with 10 identical a_0 dicts
    i_new = dict(a_0)
    items.append(i_new)

for i in items[0:5]: # change the first 5 items
    if i["what"] == "b": # try to change the 'i' to be a_1 dicts
        i = dict(a_1)
        # print(i) shows changes

for i in items: 
    print(i)
    # print(i) does not show changes
```

If the above change works then first 5 items should be the same as a_1, while the last 5 unchanged. But the printed outcome did not match my expectation and this confused me. I want to know whether I missed something. Are there any more convenient ways to change each dictionary in the list? Many thanks.

Comment: `i = dict(a_1)` does nothing useful. Try `i.update(a_1)`

Comment: Works. But may you explain a bit more why update() instead of = works?

Comment: explained in my answer

Comment: You might want to read this excellent summary about [names and values in Python](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html). Confusing in the beginning, but it will get better. Promise.

Comment: @Yuki.F when you set `i`in your loop, you overwrite your local variable, meaning you only throw away the pointer to the dict in that loop, but the real dictionary is still stored in the list

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in items[0:5]: # change the first 5 items
    if i["what"] == "b": # try to change the 'i' to be a_1 dicts
        i = dict(a_1)
        # print(i) shows changes
```

When you create the loop ... `i` is a local variable which contains the dictionary from positions `[0:5]`

When you do:

```
i = dict(a_1)
```

You are changing the local variable but not the value in the list. Iterate over the indices and change directly in the list

```
for i in range(0, 5): # change the first 5 items
    if items[i]["what"] == "b": # try to change the 'i' to be a_1 dicts
        items[i] = dict(a_1)
        # print(items[i]) shows changes
```

Now you have changed the items in the list and not the value of a local variable

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are trying to change 'i' which just holds the value of each item in the 'items' list. Try this:

```
a_0 = {"what": "b"}
a_1 = {"what": "c"}
a_2 = {"what": "d"}

items = []

for i_no in range(10):
    i_new = dict(a_0)
    items.append(i_new)

for index,i in enumerate(items[0:5]):
    if i["what"] == "b": 
        items[index] = dict(a_1)

for i in items: 
    print i
```